# Modifying category feeds in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rss, categories, feed

I know you can access category feeds via category/feed which is great however I need to modify these.

Basically I need to generate 3 feeds for every category.

1 is the original feed
2 is offset by one
3 is offset by two

I know I could do this individually for every category but this is for a site with at least 50 different categories. So `50 x 3 = 150` different feed files!

If not is there a way to target posts within a category feed? `category/feed/post=1` for example?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: have a look at this https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Categories_and_Tags

Comment: Thank you, already read that page in detail and it does not mention targeting posts or the ability to modify category feeds with offsets. I have researched into this for days, exhausted Google, asking on here as a last attempt.

Comment: Anyone? Please :(

Comment: have you try something to achieve ?